# How to send multiple variables in one single sender?

Tags: swift, variables, uibutton, sender

I'm trying to send multiple variables in one single sender to show it in the Viewcontroller that it's connected to a segue named `menuENG`. I have five buttons and each button should send different information because is a dictionary and each button is a word. But I want to do this thru one sender. I tried the following code to make it but it is not working.

p.s.: I tried making an array but Xcode goes crazy.

```
@IBAction func abstractionENG(sender:UIButton) {
  return perfomanceWithIdentifier("menuENG",sender:nil)
}
```

Comment: You can't return in an IBAction function.

Comment: You mean that all five buttons are connected to abstractionENG functions ?

Comment: what u really want? can u explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for the help fixed the issue by this way >

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

/* The following functions containts a group of conditionals which will change the scene depending  of the IBAction selected */

@IBAction func abstractionENG(sender: UIButton) {
    let data = [DiccioModel.abstraction().nameEng,DiccioModel.abstraction().descriptionEng,DiccioModel.abstraction().linkEng]
    performSegueWithIdentifier("menuENG", sender: data)
}

@IBAction func webBrowserENG(sender: UIButton) {
    let data = [DiccioModel.webBrowser().nameEng,DiccioModel.webBrowser().descriptionEng,DiccioModel.webBrowser().linkEng]
    performSegueWithIdentifier("menuENG", sender: data)
}

@IBAction func latencyENG(sender: UIButton) {
    let data = [DiccioModel.latency().nameEng,DiccioModel.latency().descriptionEng,DiccioModel.latency().linkEng]
    performSegueWithIdentifier("menuENG", sender: data)
}

@IBAction func conditionalENG(sender: UIButton) {
    let data = [DiccioModel.conditional().nameEng,DiccioModel.conditional().descriptionEng,DiccioModel.conditional().linkEng]
    performSegueWithIdentifier("menuENG", sender: data)
}


@IBAction func operatingSystemENG(sender: UIButton) {
    let data = [DiccioModel.os().nameEng,DiccioModel.os().descriptionEng,DiccioModel.os().linkEng]
    performSegueWithIdentifier("menuENG", sender: data)
}

@IBAction func abstractionESP(sender: UIButton) {
    let data = [DiccioModel.abstraction().nameEsp,DiccioModel.abstraction().descriptionEsp,DiccioModel.abstraction().linkEsp]
    performSegueWithIdentifier("menuESP", sender: data)
}

@IBAction func webBrowserESP(sender: UIButton) {
    let data = [DiccioModel.webBrowser().nameEsp,DiccioModel.webBrowser().descriptionEsp,DiccioModel.webBrowser().linkEsp]
    performSegueWithIdentifier("menuESP", sender: data)
}

@IBAction func latencyESP(sender: UIButton) {
    let data = [DiccioModel.latency().nameEsp,DiccioModel.latency().descriptionEsp,DiccioModel.latency().linkEsp]
    performSegueWithIdentifier("menuESP", sender: data)
}

@IBAction func conditionalESP(sender: UIButton) {
    let data = [DiccioModel.conditional().nameEsp,DiccioModel.conditional().descriptionEsp,DiccioModel.conditional().linkEsp]
    performSegueWithIdentifier("menuESP", sender: data)
}


@IBAction func operatingSystemESP(sender: UIButton) {
    let data = [DiccioModel.os().nameEsp,DiccioModel.os().descriptionEsp,DiccioModel.os().linkEsp]
    performSegueWithIdentifier("menuESP", sender: data)
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "menuENG") || (segue.identifier == "menuESP"){
        if let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? DefinitionViewController{
            if let data = sender as? Array<String>{
                destinationViewController.tittle = data[0]
                destinationViewController.def = data[1]
                destinationViewController.link = data[2]
            }
        }
    }



}
```

PS: note this code is connected to the DefinitionViewController ( Controller of the view) and to a model. ( project was made by M.V.C way).

Again Thx everyone for your help. hope the code help other people in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can send the dictionary and there is something wrong with this line `return perfomanceWithIdentifier("menuENG",sender:nil)`

Anyway you can seperatly identify which button is clicked by `tag` and create dictionary on base of clicked button now you can send the complete dictionary to the sender.

```
@IBAction func abstractionENG(sender:UIButton) {

        var dictSendData:[String:Any] = [:]
        if sender == btn1
        {
            dictSendData.updateValue("abc", forKey: "key1")
            dictSendData.updateValue("pqr", forKey: "key2")
        }
        else if sender == btn2
        {
            dictSendData.updateValue("xyz", forKey: "key1")
            dictSendData.updateValue("123", forKey: "key2")

        }
       else 
        {
           dictSendData.updateValue("123", forKey: "key1")
           dictSendData.updateValue("abc", forKey: "key2")
        }
 self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"menuENG", sender: dictSendData)

}
```

Comment: tags are evil. Comparing `sender` directly, e.g. `if sender == button1` is better. Or declaring a special function for every button. Don't recommend tags. They are just magic number.

Comment: @Sulthan i think tags are useful when we have not created outlet of all buttons

Comment: Exactly, for example http://benford.me/blog/12-dos-and-donts-for-ios-development/ says *"The tag property might as well be called “lazyHackUsedHere”"* which is exactly right. They are just bad code.

Answer (score 0):

1- assign segue action to IBAction function  - assign tag id to ever button

you have already implemented it .

2- your `IBAction` function should  run another function to run  `performSegue function`

example :

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "openAnotherViewController",sender: sender)
```

3- go to destination view Controller and create reciver variables "Maybe you can use optionals "  .

```
 var receiverInt :Int = 0
 var receiverInt2 :Int = 0
```

3- go to the source view Controller and pass variables

```
     // MARK: - Navigation
 // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
 // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
 // Pass the selected variable/object to the new view controller .

    if segue.identifier == "openAnotherViewController" {
        let destinationController =  segue.destination as! OtherViewControllerClass Name 
       // identify button by tag number 
       if (sender as! UIButton).tag == 200 {
        destinationController.receiverInt = self.sourceInt

        }else{
        destinationController.receiverInt2 = self.sourceInt2}

    }


 }
```

Comment: i think you forget to read `button should send different information because is a dictionary and each button is a word`

Comment: i have updated my answer to show him how to use tags . 
he didn't know how to user segue thats why i have posted example